# Can't get to run freetype in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, freetype2

I am new to Qt and Ubuntu and I tried to follow the tutorial to install Freetype. But I guess something with missing flags causes the problem. So if it´s that what do I have to do?

When I do

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

i get this error:

```
ft2build.h: No such file or directory
```

while when I do

```
#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
```

I get this error:

```
freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory
```

and

```
-I/usr/include/freetype2
```

is what I get when I do

```
freetype-config --cflags
```

Comment: Where is located really the ft2build.h

Comment: What is actual location of ftheader.h ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/freetype2"
```

In your .pro file

Comment: `INCLUDEPATH += "usr/include/freetype2"`?? absolute path `INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/include/freetype2"`